# Wordpress attachement used in several posts

Tags: wordpress

I have this code

```
    $attachments = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
) );

var_dump($attachments);
echo '</pre>';
    foreach ($attachments as $attach) {
        if ($attach->post_mime_type == 'application/pdf'){
            $parent_id = $attach->post_parent;
            $parent_title = get_the_title($parent_id);
            $parent_link = get_permalink($parent_id);
            echo $attach->post_title . ' : <a href="' . $parent_link . '">' . $parent_title . '</a><br/>';
        }
    }
```

it gives :

> fichierPDF7 : test 2
>   fichierPDF6 : test 2
>   fichierPDF5 : test 2 fichierPDF4 : test 2 fichierPDF1 - Copie :
>   brouillon fichierPDF1 - Copie (2) : brouillon fichierPDF3 : brouillon
>   fichierPDF2 : test fichierPDF1 : test

with good links, of course.

But when a same PDF file is used in more than one post.... I can't see the other.

For example fichierPDF4 is also used in two other posts but.. how reach them with the attachment?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found something, I put it here, maybe one day it could help someone

```
$custom = get_post_custom($post_id);
```

you can find all custom fields. In my case I had a custom field "pdf" witch it says how much PDF the page had. And $custom['pdf_X_le_fichier_pdf'] where X is a digit between 0 and the pdf field minus 1.
So I did something like that :

```
$custom = get_post_custom($post_id);
$guids= array();
for($i=0;$i<$custom['pdf'][0];$i++){
    $id = $custom['pdf_'.$i.'_le_fichier_pdf'][0];

    $post = get_post($id);
    $guids[] = $post->guid;

}
```